# Calendar component multiple events in cell

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I'm creating a calendar component, whereby I've defined the code as below.

```
<DndContext
onDragEnd={handleDragEnd}
>
// Generates the calendar cells
                                    <div
                                        className="grid flex-auto"
                                        style={{
                                            gridTemplateColumns: 'repeat(7, minmax(0, 1fr))',
                                            gridTemplateRows: 'repeat(96, minmax(1.25rem, 1fr))'
                                        }}
                                    >
                                        {
                                            // Generates droppables for drag 'n drop
                                        }
                                        {
                                            generateCells()
                                        }
                                        {
                                            // Events
                                        }
                                        {
                                            gridItems.map(g => g.element)
                                        }
                                        {
                                            // Right column padding
                                        }
                                        <div className="col-start-8 row-span-full grid w-8" />
                                    </div>
                                </DndContext>
```

The `generateCells` function returns a 7x96 grid of cells (with dnd-kit's useDroppable) with the following code:

```
<div
            ref={setNodeRef}
            className={cn(
                'relative',
                'overflow-visible',
                isOver && 'bg-green-100',
                ...
                'border-r border-gray-100',
                'transition ease-in-out duration-150'
            )}
            style={{
                gridRow: `${x + 1} / span 1`,
                gridColumn: `${y + 1} / span 1`,
            }}
        />
```

The `gridItems` array is defined as:

```
{
...
element: <BookingItem key={booking.id} booking={booking} />
}
```

Each BookingItem has the following style for it to render in the right spot:

```
style={{
                    gridRow: `${startRow} / span ${span}`,
                    gridColumn: `${booking.startCol + 1} / span 1`,
                    transform: CSS.Translate.toString(transform)
                }}
```

When I have multiple events in the same time / cell, right now they are overlapping (e.g., if two events in exact same time, one hides the other). I'd like to add a flexbox somewhere to have them separate into columns, but just can't figure out how. If I add a `<div className='flex'>` before the `gridItems.map...` call, none of the events attach in the right col/row of the calendar. I've tried a few different approaches, including making each column a flexbox, but that has the unintended effect of shrinking events even where they don't overlap.

Can anyone please help? I've been trying to figure this out for hours now!

[image: unintended overlap effect]